# Content by section in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have installed Joomla! 2.5.4 on my localserver. In the jommla 1.5 there is option in admin panel for "content section" and "content by section". In jommla 2.5.4 there is no option like that. I have searched on net about this they says "content by section" is removed. I want to show content according to section in joomla2.5.4 similar to joomla 1.5. how can i do that.

Answer (score 2):

In Joomla 1.5 there was a two-tier system of Section -> Category. This has been replaced since 1.6 with an infinitely nestable category system. So now you can arrange your content like: Category -> Sub-Category -> Sub-Sub-Category .... etc. It's much more flexible.